# Core Graphics Rotating a Path

Tags: iphone, cgcontext, core-graphics

This should be a simple one, basically I have a few paths drawn with core graphics, and I want to be able to rotate them (for convenience). I've tried using CGContextRotateCTM(context); but it's not rotating anything. Am I missing something?

Here's the source for drawRect

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.5);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetShadow(context, CGSizeMake(0, 1), 0);

CGContextBeginPath(context);

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 13.5, 13.5);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 30.5, 13.5);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 30.5, 30.5);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 13.5, 30.5);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 13.5, 13.5);

CGContextClosePath(context);

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 26.2, 13.5);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 26.2, 17.8);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 30.5, 17.8);

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 17.8, 13.5);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 17.8, 17.8);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 13.5, 17.8);

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 13.5, 26.2);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 17.8, 26.2);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 17.8, 30.5);

CGContextStrokePath(context);

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0, 0), 0, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);

CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(26.2, 13.5, 4.3, 4.3));
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(13.5, 13.5, 4.3, 4.3));
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(13.5, 26.2, 4.3, 4.3));

CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI / 4);
}
```

Comment: Can you include some source code? The CGContextRotateCTM(context) is the correct function, but it is difficult to see if you have an error in your code if you don't include any!

Comment: I updated my original post to include the source, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Place this before drawing/filling your figure to translate to origin, rotate and then translate back to the point it should appear to rotate around:

```
static inline float radians(double degrees) { return degrees * M_PI / 180; }

CGContextTranslateCTM(c, midX, midY);
CGContextRotateCTM(c, radians(-73));
CGContextTranslateCTM(c, -midX, -midY);
```

Change the angle value passed to CGContextRotateCTM to make the figure point in another direction.

Comment: This needs more love, this worked for me and is exactly what i needed

Comment: Just spent forever on this junk. Landed here after hours and realized I up voted this 2 years ago. This is a really simple solution that works flawlessly. Totally agree @DFectuoso :)

Comment: What is midX and midY

Comment: (midX, midY) is the point around which your object should appear to rotate.

Comment: I put the rotation code in the answer **before** `CGContextBeginPath(context);` and any subsequent `CGContextMoveToPoint` / `CGContextAddLineToPoint` calls... Initially I had interpreted the answer to mean: *place before* `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor` and/or `CGContextDrawPath` calls... but in that case the rotation was not applied. It needed to be before the *path* was created. Thanks.